# Error when attempting to assign values to a queue object [Java OOP]

Tags: java, arrays, oop, queue

So I have this assignment which is meant to simulate passengers waiting at a boarding gate and we need to create a menu with different options. For it we have to have two classes and a main program and the entire thing is based on a queue. My problem is that my most basic part of the program, adding passengers in the queue, is not working and it displays the following when prompted for a display after passengers have been added:

The queue: 
airport.Passenger@55f96302

Ignoring the fact that the program is nowhere near complete, this is what I have so far:

Main:

```
 public class Airport {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassengerQueue queue1= new PassengerQueue();
        Passenger[]  ArrayOfPassenger = new Passenger[20];
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
        String optionMenu;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            ArrayOfPassenger[i]= new Passenger();

        char letter;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter display option [A-add passenger, V- view passenger queue, D- delete passenger from queue, S- store passengerQueue data into file, L- load passengerQueue data from file] or 'X' to stop: ");
            optionMenu = input.next();
            letter = optionMenu.charAt(0);

            switch (letter) {
                case 'A':
                    queue1.AddPassenger();
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    queue1.display();
                case 'D':                       
                    break;
                case 'S':                      
                    break;
                case 'L':                       
                    break;                       
            }

        } while (letter != 'X');    
    }
}
```

Passenger Class:

```
public class Passenger {
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private int secondsInQueue;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getname() {
        return firstName= " "+surname;
    }

    public void setName (String fName, String sName) {
        firstName = fName;
        surname = sName;
    }

    public Passenger () {
        firstName = "";
        surname = "";
    }
}
```

Passenger Queue class:

```
public class PassengerQueue {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    private Passenger[] qArray =new Passenger [20];
    private int first = 0;
    private int last = 0;
    private int maxStayInQueue;
    static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 20;
    public PassengerQueue() {
    for (int i = 0;i < 20; i++)
        qArray[i]= new Passenger();
}

public void AddPassenger() {
    System.out.println("Enter passenger's First Name:");
    String FirstName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter passenger's surname:");
    String Surname= input.next();
    qArray[last].setName(FirstName, Surname);
    last++;
    if(last == qArray.length){
        last = 0;
    }
}

public void display() {
    System.out.println("The queue: ");
    for(int i = first; i < last; i++)
        System.out.println(qArray[i]);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == 0;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return last == 19;
}
```

}

My question is what am I doing wrong here, when assigning values in the queue1 and what can I do to resolve it? I've been trying to understand for a while now, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, Java does not know what is the proper string representation of a Passenger class is. To tell System.out.println() how to represent Passenger as a String, override the toString() method. So in the Passenger class, add something like:

```
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + surname;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, this has been driving me crazy!